# Using unix-based package on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I'm really new to Linux, Ubuntu and all related things. My question is that can I use a unix-based program on Ubuntu as well?

I installed neo4j on Kali Linux from this [link](https://neo4j.com/download-center/#community) and using this [unix.tar.gz](https://neo4j.com/artifact.php?name=neo4j-community-4.0.3-unix.tar.gz) file to install it on my Kali linux. My question is that can I use the same file to install neo4j on Ubuntu as well?

Comment: And how is unix related to your question? unix is not linux.

Comment: @Pilot6 I was confused about these terms, I thought unix is related to Linux

Comment: UNIX is proprietary which is why the GNU (Gnu is Not Unix) operating system was created (with strong resemblances). Then came the Linux kernel forming GNU/Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is "unix" in the file name, this is for Linux. Kali Linux and Ubuntu are both Linux and in fact, this should works on any Linux distribution. You can use it on Ubuntu.